# ASP.NET Web Application Azure Settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, azure, settings

We're currently refactoring our ASP.NET 4.0 Web Application to run on both plain old IIS and Azure. For the Settings (in the `Properties` namespace), I'd like to implement the [State Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternState.aspx) with an `AzureSettingsState` and a `StandaloneSettingsState`, which both provide settings getter methods.

Now could anybody help me figuring out how ASP.NET deserializes the non-String values (e.g. `TimeSpan` or `StringCollection`), so that I can deserialize them on my own in the context class? All settings seem to be strings there.

```
public abstract class ConfigStateBase
{
    public abstract string GetSettingValue(string setting);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this, still don't know if it works :D

```
public class AzureConfig:StandaloneConfig
{
    protected override string GetAppSetting(string name)
    {
        return RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(name);
    }

    protected override string GetConnectionString(string name)
    {
        return RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(name);
    }
}

public class StandaloneConfig
{
    public IndexedSetting AppSettings { get; private set; }
    public IndexedSetting ConnectionStrings { get; private set; }

    public StandaloneConfig()
    {
        AppSettings = new IndexedSetting(GetAppSetting);
        ConnectionStrings = new IndexedSetting(GetConnectionString);
    }

    protected virtual String GetAppSetting(String name)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[name];
    }

    protected virtual String GetConnectionString(String name)
    {
        var cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name];
        if (cs != null)
            return cs.ConnectionString;
        else
            return null;
    }

    public class IndexedSetting
    {
        Func<String, String> _getParameter;

        public IndexedSetting(Func<String,String> getParameter)
        {
            _getParameter = getParameter;
        }

        public String this[String name]
        {
            get { return _getParameter(name); }
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to tell Azure to use it!

```
    static AzureConfig _config = new AzureConfig(); 

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher((configName, configSetter) =>
        {
            configSetter(_config.AppSettings[configName]);
        });

    }
```

If you use it let me know, I wanna get paid ... I mean I wanna know if it works :D